# Appcelerator studio: how to set logging level to trace?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

How to set logging level in the Appcelerator Studio to show trace messages (posted by Ti.API.trace()) in the console?
version of the studio is 4.4.0.201511241829
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Studio, you can change the log level on the Console Window as seen below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Run Config` to run as `trace` instead `info`